# How to add helpers to fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Okay, I'm using something like

```
 $.fancybox(  $("#savesofrm") );
```

to open a div that has some basic (textarea, etc) form elements in it. It works.

I want to pass more options, like `helpers` in. Not sure how. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
$.fancybox($("#savesofrm"),{
 // add options here
 helpers: {
   title  : { type : "inside" },
   thumbs : {
     width: 50,
     height: 50
   }
 }
});
```